# GitLab/GitLab-CI Omnibus package configure sidekiq concurrency

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

My server has way too many sidekiq processes running for my needs in my GitLab install, both GitLab and GitLab-CI were running a ton of them. I have it running on DigitalOcean droplet with 1GB Ram 20GB SSD Disk on Ubuntu 14.04 x64, and it was regularly telling me I need to restart my server, and when I check `htop` I have 17-30 sidekiq processes running `gitlab-rails [0 of 25 busy]`

There is no clear documentation on how to change the number of sidekiq processes, or the concurrency, for the Omnibus install of GitLab/GitLab-CI.

What is the best way to adjust this and have it persist through upgrades?

Answer (score 3):

I still have a problem with the number of processes slowly growing over time, but the best solution I have come up with so far for limiting the concurrency setting is to alter these two files:

`/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/initializers/4_sidekiq.rb`

`/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-ci/config/initializers/3_sidekiq.rb`

By adding `config.options[:concurrency] = 2` inside `Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|`

So, for example, my final `4_sidekiq.rb` file looks like this:

```
# Custom Redis configuration
config_file = Rails.root.join('config', 'resque.yml')

resque_url = if File.exists?(config_file)
               YAML.load_file(config_file)[Rails.env]
             else
               "redis://localhost:6379"
             end

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.options[:concurrency] = 2
  config.redis = {
    url: resque_url,
    namespace: 'resque:gitlab'
  }

  config.server_middleware do |chain|
    chain.add Gitlab::SidekiqMiddleware::ArgumentsLogger if ENV['SIDEKIQ_LOG_ARGUMENTS']
    chain.add Gitlab::SidekiqMiddleware::MemoryKiller if ENV['SIDEKIQ_MEMORY_KILLER_MAX_RSS']
  end
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = {
    url: resque_url,
    namespace: 'resque:gitlab'
  }
end
```

Comment: It solves part of my problem, I was successful in getting the concurrency to change, but I still have a problem with the number of processes slowly growing over time.

Comment: Are the sidekiq processes saving their PIDs in some pidfile? If they do, you can send them a [USR1+TERM](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Signals) inside your `Sidekiq.configure_server` block, so that each new server will take care of killing the existing ones. Not a real solution (preventing them from starting in the first place), but should help.

Comment: so when you upgrade you're 'fix' is hosed

Answer (score 3):

At least for gitlab-omnibus we can do that easy in /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb

```
##################
# GitLab Sidekiq #
##################

# sidekiq['log_directory'] = "/var/log/gitlab/sidekiq"
# sidekiq['shutdown_timeout'] = 4
# sidekiq['concurrency'] = 25
  sidekiq['concurrency'] = 5
```

So now it says "[0 of 5 busy]"

Comment: This is not working, I just tried now and I still have the 25 threads.

Comment: It works... run gitlab reconfigure command.. and reboot you server... I significantly decreased amount of used RAM. You made something wrong...

Comment: "reboot you server" ... come on. @Stefan Liedle's solution works fine, without rebooting the server.

Comment: Do you need screenshot from htop? It works.. 100%... what you made wrong - I do not know.. after reconfiguration sometimes it is required to reboot server or restart gitlab.... So just update your hands.sys...

Comment: OMG you're awesome

Comment: this works correctly, you need to run `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` and `gitlab-ctl restart sidekiq`

Comment: Any best practices when to use which number for the sidekiq concurrency??

Answer (score 0):

Check out: [hardware requirements](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/requirements.html#hardware-requirements) for GitLab, and killing sidekick processes is a no go, GitLab depends on it to perform a lot of async actions.

1G of memory is not enough!